# Are how-to-debug questions, even in disguise, useful?

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across (and flagged), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215644/how-to-get-entry-from-mongodb-using-node-js).  At first glance, definitely looks help-vampirey.  There's no real shown attempt to solve the problem and just a code dump on the screen.

On second glance, however, I feel like there's a kernel of utility in this question.  It looks like the user is really asking "how do I debug this connection?" even they may not realize it.  The given answer, while correct, doesn't really help any followers-on to understand Mongo.

That leaves two questions

1. Is SO a place for saying "How do I debug in situation X?"
2. If #1, is it right/wrong to edit that question until it actually asks for help debugging, instead of just being a crappy code dump?

Comment: In my experience even if it the user is asking for help debugging the general consensus is that this is not the place to ask for help debugging code. At least not without showing a decent effort to do their own debugging before posting.